# Does "poco a poco accel. fino al misura 25" sound like proper Italian tempo mark?

Tags: notation, tempo

Is ""poco a poco accel. fino al misura 25" correct tempo mark in Italian for "step by step accelerate until measure 25"?

Comment: There's no harm in being specific, but you can also just say "poco a poco accel.," and then in m 25 "a tempo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond the obvious "*accelerando*", there are various ways to note a gradual increase in tempo; "*di piu in piu animato*" (ex. Saint-Saens, Danse Bacchanale, lit. "more and more animated"); "*cresc. e stretto poco a poco*" (Grieg, In the Hall of the Mountain King, "stretto poco a poco" being literally "gradually tighter" or "narrower", i.e. referring to the time interval between the notes).

As others have pointed out, if the accelerando is not until the end of a piece (in which case one can simply append "*al fine*"), the end point is more practically indicated by a new tempo marking (coupling it with a rehearsal mark  is definitively a good idea) or other mark that makes this clear, such as an extension line for the accelerando. In a case like this, I would very likely pencil in a mark on the sheet music if it were not already present

In any case, although that is a bit moot, and ignoring that musical Italian is not always proper Italian (for ex. "fine" is also feminine), "misura" is grammatically feminine ([see the dictionary](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/misura/)) and thus, to be strictly correct, it would be "alla misura".

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I actually translated from English to Italian via ChatGPT. I guess, it does not know enough about music Italian :-)

Answer (score 2):

Musical directions are not always correct Italian, and don't really need to be as long as the meaning is clear. But a much more usual way of notating something like this is write just "poco a poco accel." and then at M.25 add "a tempo" or give a new tempo indication. Musicians don't read measure numbers while they are playing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the music wouldn't be performed by an Italian-only orchestra, it may be most effective to simply write that in English.

Comment: First thought: "well, I want everything in the same language", but then, the title is in English, so it is already two languages :-)

Comment: I do think tempo indications in English is more and more commonplace these days.

Comment: All classically trained musicians worldwide learn to understand 'musical Italian' but not all of them understand English.